# Cutting a raster based on a grid (vector file) in ArcGIS Pro, do I first have to convert them to the same coordinate system?

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, convert, clip, vector-grid

I have a raster file (TIFF) in WGS 1984 and a vector grid file (North America Lambert Conformal Conic). I want to average the value of the raster for each grid cell.

I supposed I would first have to convert the raster file to the same coordinate system. However, having done that, I noticed that the grid cell size was considerably bigger in the new raster file. That means I would lose some data when calculating the mean values based on the transformed raster.

Also, I am not sure which transformation would work best in this situation, so I just chose WGS 1984 (ITRF00) to NAD 1983.

Should I 1) still do it, 2) maybe adjust the grid cell size (?) or rather just 3) use the original raster as it looks okay on the map?

Comment: It is *far* better to project your grid (vector) to match your raster; when a raster is projected it is resampled which uses the chosen resampling method to adjust the values of the cells, so you can no longer trust the results. Not that you need to project anything provided the coordinate sytems are defined and compatable, you would only need to project the grid if there is a specific transformation you need to use. When you say WGS 1984 do you mean WGS 1984 Geographic (EPSG:4326) or a UTM projection?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I thought the same, but my final data must be in equal area projection so I chose the path of converting the raster.  I mean a geographic coordinate system (EPSG:4326), I do not think the raster data are projected.

Comment: Additionally, I also have another vector shapefile that I want to average to the same vector grid. In that case, I suppose I will have to transform one of the vector files before calculations?

Comment: You would only need to project your data if the datums require a specific translation, NAD83 to WGS84 is a good example of incompatable datums but I'm not informed enough in northern hemisphere datums to offer any advice on which transformation is suitable. Please consider projecting your grid to EPSG:4326 to match the raster, redo your cell statistics and compare the result, it might surprise you how different the results are. Be sure to set your environment cell size and snap raster to your input raster to avoid resampling.